# Impala Query executing order

Tags: impala

I ran the "Explain" of my Impala query and got the following result. I am trying to understand it: is the executing order just bottom up? Then what does the numeric number mean if it is not the executing order? Thanks!

```
   Estimated Per-Host Requirements: Memory=2.08GB VCores=2
    WARNING: The following tables are missing relevant table and/or column statistics.
    my_db.v1, my_db.v2

    10:EXCHANGE [UNPARTITIONED]
    |
    06:ANALYTIC
    |  functions: last_value(my_v_id), last_value(my__arrival_ts), last_value(version)
    |  partition by: id, trunc(my__arrival_ts, 'D')
    |  order by: my__arrival_ts ASC
    |  window: RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    |
    05:SORT
    |  order by: id ASC NULLS FIRST, trunc(my__arrival_ts, 'D') ASC NULLS FIRST, my__arrival_ts ASC
    |
    09:EXCHANGE [HASH(id,trunc(my__arrival_ts, 'D'))]
    |
    04:ANALYTIC
    |  functions: last_value(build)
    |  partition by: version
    |  order by: my__arrival_day ASC
    |  window: RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    |
    03:SORT
    |  order by: version ASC NULLS FIRST, my__arrival_day ASC
    |
    08:EXCHANGE [HASH(version)]
    |
    02:HASH JOIN [INNER JOIN, BROADCAST]
    |  hash predicates: v1__fk = v1.id
    |  runtime filters: RF000 <- v1.id
    |
    |--07:EXCHANGE [BROADCAST]
    |  |
    |  00:SCAN HDFS [my_db.v1]
    |     partitions=1791/2994 files=1956 size=125.30MB
    |     predicates: my__is_external
    |
    01:SCAN HDFS [my_db.vm]
       partitions=2058/2058 files=2094 size=9.98GB
       runtime filters: RF000 -> v1__fk
```

Answer (score 1):

The numerical numbers are just PlannodeId used by the planner. The execution order is logically bottom up, but in runtime, the whole plan tree is broken into pieces of plan fragments, which are executed concurrently and hopefully distributely by one coordinator. You can refer to impala's profile webpage which by default listening on port 25000 to see the dynamic execution process.

`set explain_level=3;` gets you full fragmented plan result.